# PHP/MySQL connection

Tags: php, html, database

I think it is a foolish question but I cannot understand why it is happening... I want to connect to my MySQL database with this simple code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>File1</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <?php
    $con=mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die("Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysql_error());
    $db=mysql_select_db("Users",$con) or die("Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysql_error());

    if (mysql_error()) {
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysql_error();
    }
    ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

As user, I use root. The problem is that root needs a password. So, with this code I should obtain on my screen "Failed to connect to MySQL", right? However, the screen is white.

Why is white instead of appearing "Failed to connect..."?

Many thanks!

Comment: Please look into PDO and MySQLi for database connections. Mysql_* functions are becoming deprecated

Comment: No errors found in your code!!! thats why it showing blank page

Comment: Use of `mysql_connect` function is depreciated. use `mysqli_connect` function instead.

Comment: I tested on my local and it seem fine. Check you php.ini for error reporting maybe?

Comment: What kind of file is it, is the php being executed, what does the source of the parsed file in the browser look like?

Comment: <?php
ini_set('display_errors','on'); // or 'true' - go nuts!
ini_set('error_reporting',E_ALL);
?>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think errors are not displayed in your server , Inside your php.ini add or change value of this line:

```
display_errors = on
```

Then restart your web server.

Comment: I'm really curious as to how displaying errors would affect the output of `die()` here...

Answer (score 0):

Probably a simple case of fatal errors being hidden?

Use this to turn errors on:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', true);
```

Answer (score 0):

In your page, Your connection got established, there is no success message, there is no other browser output aswell. So that it seems blank screen.

```
if ($con) {       
     echo "Connection successful!!";
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason you're not getting any output is because of the `or die`. 
die() stops the execution of the script.

```
$con=mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
$db=mysql_select_db("Users",$con);
```

Comment: It does stop the execution of the script; but it should also output the contents of the string you pass in as a parameter.

Comment: @andrewsi- Displaying the string depends on the `display_errors` config value. User's echo should display regardless of display_errors' value.

Comment: `display_errors` configures whether you get to see errors, warnings, and notices generated internally by PHP. If your display_errors settings is set to hide everything, the contents of `die()` will still show up.

Answer (score 0):

Your `$db` variable is unassigned.

Use this instead, by removing `$db=`

```
mysql_select_db("Users",$con) or die("Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysql_error());
```

Plus, `mysql_` functions are deprecated. For more information on this, visit the PHP.net Website.

- http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-db-query.php

I suggest you start using `mysqli_` with prepared statements or PDO instead.

**WARNING**

This extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and will be removed in the future. Instead, the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extension should be used. See also MySQL: choosing an API guide and related FAQ for more information.

Answer (score 0):

The difference between error display on or off, is the warning you get before the script exits through the `die()` command.

You will always see the message printed by `die()` at the end of the output as that is unrelated to any php error handling:

> Failed to connect to MySQL: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'
>   (using password: NO)

The only reason I can think of that the message not shows, is that the php is not getting executed; for example if your file is an `.html` file instead of a `.php` file. That would lead to a blank page as the opening `<` of the php section will be seen as the opening of an html tag and the same applies to the closing tag.

Checking the source of the output would confirm that.